# How to manipulate lists with lens in Haskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm a beginner of the lens library.
I'm trying to extract a list from some data structure.

I wonder how to implement `f` that satisfies:

```
("a",[(0,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'c')]) ^. _2 . f === [0,1,2]
```

With a struggle, I found an answer.

```
g :: Functor f => Getting a s a -> (forall b. Getting (f b) (f s) (f a))
g = to . fmap . view
f = g _1
```

Is there any library function that corresponds to `g`? 
Otherwise, Is there any more elegant way to implement such `f`?

Answer (score 4):

I would go for

```
("a",[(0,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'c')]) ^.. _2 . traverse . _1
```

(Note the `^..` instead of `^.` because this is a traversal.)